# Intersections between a function and its Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

Suppose $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open, $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth (not necessarily real analytic) function, $x_0 \in D$, and $T_n$ is the degree $n$ Taylor polynomial of $f$ centered at $x_0$. Let $S=\{ x \in D : f(x)=T_n(x) \}$. It is not hard to see that $S$ is closed and contains $x_0$. What else can be said about it (possibly with additional hypotheses)? I suppose the most general possible question is: can $S$ be an arbitrary closed subset of $D$?

I know that $S$ need not be finite; for instance, the constant approximation of $\sin$ at $\pi/2$ has $S=\pi/2 + 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$. I also know that $S$ need not be discrete, at least if the domain is not compact; for instance, if the domain is $(0,1]$ and $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ and we take the constant approximation at any point, then $S$ has a limit point at $0$.

Major edit: evidently $D \setminus S$ can at least be any open interval, because $f$ could be a bump function supported interval $I$ and take a point of expansion outside $I$, in which case $T_n$ will be zero and $T_n - f$ will be zero exactly outside $I$. Can we use this to prove that $S$ can be any closed set containing $x_0$?

Comment: $e^{-1/s)$ on the right half line and $0$ on the left gives you an example (of a smooth function) where any Taylor polynomial (all constant 0) agrees with $f$ on the entire left half line.

Comment: If f is analytic but not a polynomial then it is discrete.

Comment: I made some modifications to broaden the question after I caught some trivial cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add this because I'm not sure if Robert Israel is giving the same answer. Let $E \subset \mathbb {R}$ be closed, with $0\in E.$ Then there exists $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R})$ such that $g=0$ on $E$ and $g>0$ on $\mathbb {R}\setminus E.$ Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n.$ Define

$$f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}g(x) + P(x).$$

Then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}),$ the $n$th order Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$ is $P,$ and the set where $f=P$ is precisely the set $E.$

Answer (score 0):

Outside a neighbourhood of $x_0$,  $T_n - f$ is an arbitrary smooth function.
So essentially you're asking what can be said about the zero set of an arbitrary smooth function.  That can be any closed subset of $\mathbb R$.